# Parsing JSON With Requests In Django

Tags: python, json, django

I am making an api call with requests in a django application. I keep getting a key error on name. The json response is pretty large so I am only picking certain fields out to use. But the error is on the very first item in the json list.

The first couple lines of the json looks like this,

```
"cards": [
    {
      "name": "Air Elemental",
      "manaCost": "{3}{U}{U}",
      "cmc": 5,
      "colors": [
        "Blue"
      ],
      "type": "Creature — Elemental",
      "types": [
        "Creature"
      ],
      "subtypes": [
        "Elemental"
      ],
```

And in my view I am parsing the json like this,

```
def graphs(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        parsedData = []
        req = requests.get('https://api.magicthegathering.io/v1/cards')
        jsonList = []
        jsonList.append(json.loads(req.content.decode()))
        cardData = {}
        for cards in jsonList:
            cardData['name'] = cards['name']
            cardData['manaCost'] = cards['manaCost']
            cardData['colors'] = cards['colors']
            cardData['type'] = cards['type']
            cardData['rarity'] = cards['rarity']
            cardData['set'] = cards['set']
            cardData['text'] = cards['text']
            cardData['flavor'] = cards['flavor']
            cardData['artist'] = cards['artist']
            cardData['power'] = cards['power']
            cardData['toughness'] = cards['toughness']
            cardData['layout'] = cards['layout']
            cardData['multiverseid'] = cards['multiverseid']
            cardData['id'] = cards['id']
        parsedData.append(cardData)
        return render(request, 'graphs/graphs.html', {'data': parsedData})
    else:
        return redirect('index')
```

The Error

```
KeyError at /graphs/graphs/
'name'
```

And in my view I am accessing the data like this,

```
 {% for key in cards %}
                      <tr>
                          <td>{{ key.name }}</td>
                          <td>{{ key.manaCost }}</td>
                          <td>{{ key.colors }}</td>
                          <td>{{ key.type }}</td>
                          <td>{{ key.rarity }}</td>
                          <td>{{ key.set }}</td>
                          <td>{{ key.text }}</td>
                          <td>{{ key.flavor }}</td>
                          <td>{{ key.artist }}</td>
                          <td>{{ key.power }}</td>
                          <td>{{ key.toughness }}</td>
                          <td>{{ key.layout }}</td>
                          <td>{{ key.multiverseid }}</td>
                          <td>{{ key.id }}</td>
                      </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
```

Why am I receiving the key error?

Comment: Can't you use [`req.json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) to directly convert response to JSON object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
json.loads(req.content.decode())
```

You get a dictionary with one key, `cards`.

```
{'cards': [<list of cards>]}
```

It doesn't make sense to append that to `jsonList`, because then you have,

```
[{'cards': [<list of cards>]}
```

and when you loop through that list, you get the single dictionary that you started with. As we said before, that dictionary has a single key, `cards`, so you get the key error when you try to access the `name` key that doesn't exist.

You really want to loop through `[<list of cards>]`, so set `jsonList` to that list instead.

```
    req = requests.get('https://api.magicthegathering.io/v1/cards')
    jsonData = json.loads(req.content.decode())
    jsonList = jsonData['cards']
    for cards in jsonList:
        cardData = {}  # move this line inside the loop
        cardData['name'] = cards['name']
        ...
        # make sure this line is inside the loop so that you append
        # every card to parsedData
        parsedData.append(cardData)
```

As mentioned in the comments and other answers, you could use the request's `json()` method to simplify your code:

```
    req = requests.get('https://api.magicthegathering.io/v1/cards')
    jsonList = req.json()['cards']
    for cards in jsonList:
        ...
```

Comment: Do I still access it the same way in the template? for key in cards {{ key.name }}
Or would it be cardData instead of cards? Because I am iterating through the new dict we created?

Comment: In your `return render()` line, you have passed a list `data` to the template. Therefore you can do `{% for card in data %}{{ card.name}}...{% endfor %}`.

Comment: I am sorry I really want to understand this. Where is "data coming into play here?" We ca;; ot cardData. but when I use data the first name renders. Is data just built into the template ?

Comment: In the `return render()` line, you have passed the dictionary `{'data': parsedData}`. That means that you can access `parsedData` from your view as `data` in the template. I'm not sure why you use a different name in the view and template. You might find it less confusing if you do `{'parsedData': parsedData}`.

Comment: Yes thank you for taking the time to point that out. Jesus. Thank you

Comment: No problem, hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Because the key `name` cannot be found in the `cards` dict.

To debug this, you should probably do a print of each cards dict and see what dict is irregular.

Good luck!

Comment: cardData['name'] = cards['name']

Comment: Do a print of cards to see if the name is actually in there.

Answer (score 2):

Wait, your json is

```
"cards": [
    {"name": "Air Elemental",...}
]
```

Then you load it like this

```
jsonList = []
jsonList.append(json.loads(req.content.decode()))
```

Doesn't it make jsonList

```
[
    {"cards": [{"name": "Air Elemental",...}]}
]
```

When you iterate over it, you'll get `{"cards": [{"name": "Air Elemental",...}]}`, and apparently it doesn't have key `name`. You need to iterate over `jsonList['cards']`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have done this in 3 other apps and it worked perfectly. The decode is because it get a the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes' without the decode. Will you please show me an example of your suggestion with list? I assume I am having problems because of the format of the json is not like the other 3 apps I did this in.

Comment: What I can see from your post is like @laike9m. It's not about the decode method, but your json object. Why not print the `cards` object to see what exactly it is? @wuno

Comment: When I print(req.content) all the json dumps. I am super confused after seeing all your answers. Like I said the last three apps I wrote I did this the same way. Can you please be more specific with what looks wrong with me code or maybe show me a better way to do this? I would greatly appreciate you.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation for requests [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), `jsonList = req.json()` will assign a dictionary / list of dicts corresponding to the JSON you receive from the external API resource (and is probably more readable than calling `json.loads(...)`.

I would suspect that the KeyError you are receiving is being thrown at your line `cardData['name'] = cards['name']` because the JSON decoding process isn't working as you expect.

Failing that, have you checked that you're iterating through the correct template variable (`for key in data`) since that seems to be what you're passing through to the template.